# How to ensure parameters have specific properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

how to make data2 and data3 work and data1 error with type like in the following code?

I want to make sure that if the user just enters params `{name: 'aa', age: 20}` it is an error, because parameters need to include data type date(key name can be anything) like `{name: 'aa', age: 20, born: new Date('10-10-2020')`

```
const data1 = {
  name: 'Lorem',
  age: 12
}

const data2 = {
  name: 'Lorem',
  age: 12,
  born: new Date('10/10/1990')
}

const data3 = {
  name: 'epsum',
  age: 12,
  died: new Date('10/10/1990')
}

interface PropsA {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const test = (inputParams: PropsA & { [x: string]: Date }) => {
  return inputParams
}

test(data1) //it should be an error because it doesn't have a value with data type Date other than age and name

//how to make this work and not error?
test(data2) 
test(data3)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggjDAvDA3gKBjMBAWwFMAuGAcgBkQAnEoygGjxgQHNyYUAmHAL44coSLETJeGbG0KkKNeoxZtO3Pq3wAjemApgSAdxgARJCQAUlFAAYA9LYcBOJzcoBKQcNHR4SBADM0rj4ctyUJAAOEACuTJrsXBQabHAAliRw%20kam5laOBS5unkI4aWBQJHQAZgjAJDAACnQg0QCCMqHE3NB05RwA3KpJBHFaVUOlPrCVvpgW5ZExUI0IdMQQFM2tEB0AZNgwANoAHhS9-QC6FGaVMALuGAB8nTAMUDF0YDCLy6vrRAgXhwsygFgkqEedjsEAAFiAYgAbOAwKotOjCaHw4xEBAAawaUFhaQgMEM9Dx7DAKLAIFgaPoAH4QSRoOD-LxHiy2RCAp4gA)

Comment: Why can't you add the property `born` in the interface `PropsA` ?

Comment: because the key doesn't have to be named "born" it could just be "died" and so on

Comment: the name of the key can be random as long as the data type is Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible with a generic utility type to validate the given type:

```
type HasDate<T> = Date extends T[keyof T] ? T : never;

const test = <T extends PropsA>(inputParams: HasDate<T>) => {
  return inputParams;
};
```

TS will be smart enough to infer `T` through `HasDate`.

```
test(data1) // ! errors
test(data2) // ok
test(data3) // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2p8xm)

---

Your attempt doesn't work since `{ [x: string]: Date }` means all keys must have Date values. That obviously isn't the case for `PropA`, so `data2` and `data3` fail.